# "CNAME record already exists in the zone" when creating SPF txt records

Tags: dns, cname, spf

I am setting up mailgun.com to use with my website.

But when I add dns record with type `txt` name `www.example.com` and value `v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all` 
as suggested in mailgun setup:

[image]

I get the error that specified cname record already exists in the zone

[image]

Here are my dns records configuration right now:

[image]
What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SPF records should be on the root domain, not the www subdomain. So set the `TXT` record on `example.com` instead of `www.example.com` and that should give you what you need.

From your screenshots it looks like you're trying to set up the www subdomain in Mailgun, which probably isn't what you want. Change to just the root domain there, otherwise you may be sending `something@www.example.com` emails.

Comment: 1)okay i did it and dns record is saved now but hostname `example.com` changed to @  automatically  - is it ok?

Comment: Lots of DNS providers will show an `@` in place of a subdomain, so you know it points to the root domain.

Comment: 2)Change to just the root domain there - do you mean that I should delete `www.example.com` from mailgun domains and add `example.com` and follow given instructions?

Comment: Unless they let you edit the domain inline, that may be the way to do it.